# Why are my styles showing up on desktop view but not showing up on a physical device when running "share abc123.com" inside Vagrant box?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, vagrant, vagrant-share

Anyone have any idea why whenever I run `share abc123.com` while in my Vagrabt box, the ngrok URL won't display styles on a physical device but does display styles on a desktop view?  I've connected my iPhone to my Macbook to check Safari if my style sheets are showing up - absolutely none of them are showing up in the inspector when checking the Network tab, it's completely blank.

However, when I check the console I see this error:

`[blocked] The page at https://abc123.ngrok.io/ was not allowed to run insecure content from http://abc123.com//comp/public/css/build/views/live/user-validation-live.css?id=000088e99bfda00d3227.`

That double `//` is suspicious, maybe that could be why?  But I'm not sure.

Furthermore, I've checked `cd /etc` and I've noticed I don't even have an `nginx` dirctory.  I don't think this could be an issue because the styles show up perfectly fine on Desktop view as intended.

Anyone know what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all

> ...was not allowed to run insecure content...

If you look more closely at the error, you are loading https://abc123.ngrok.io/ which is a **secure** connection (as it runs over HTTPS).

That page is then trying to load a stylesheet from http://abc123.com//comp/public/css/build/views/live/user-validation-live.css?id=000088e99bfda00d3227 which is an **insecure** connection (as it runs over HTTP).

Fix that asset up to load over HTTPS and it will load without issue (or at least without being blocked due to an insecure connection).

Whilst there is a double `//` for your asset, this won't actually stop the asset from loading and is unrelated to the issue at hand.